# AttributeError: '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'regex'

Tags: python, regex, django

My urls.py looks like this; can anyone explain where the error (AttributeError: '**proxy**' object has not attribute 'regex') is coming from? Because the error message isn't giving me any place where the error is coming from, so I'm really confused. Thanks!

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
#from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name = "homepage.html")),
    reverse_lazy("homepage.html"),
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')), # grappelli URLS

    url(r"^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r"^account/", include("account.urls")),

    # url(r"^search/", include("haystack.urls")),

    # WIBO URLs
    url(r'^cards/', include('cards.urls')),
    url(r'^contacts/', include('contacts.urls')),
    url(r'^invoice/', include('invoice.urls')),
    url(r'^employee/',include('employee.urls')),
    url(r'^sapub/request/$', 'wibo.views.sapub_request', name='jobrequeseturl'),
    url(r'^wibo/logout-all-users/$', 'wibo.views.logout_all_users', name='logoutallurl'),
    url(r'^wibo/cardmigrationextra00091/$', 'wibo.views.cards_migration_extras_0009_1', name='cardsmigrationextra0009url'),
    url(r'^wibo/cardmigrationextra00092/$', 'wibo.views.cards_migration_extras_0009_2', name='cardsmigrationextra0009url'),
    url(r'^wibo/cardmigrationextra00093/$', 'wibo.views.cards_migration_extras_0009_3', name='cardsmigrationextra0009url'),
    url(r"^reports/", include('reports.urls')),
    #url(r"^printsmart/$",direct_to_template,{"template":"printsmart_request.html"}, name="printsmarturl"),
    url(r"^printsmart/$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="printsmart_request.html")),
    url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
    )

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
#reverse(urlpatterns)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 268, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 110, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 45, in server_error
    return http.HttpResponseServerError(template.render())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 74, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 135, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 135, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 493, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 579, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 433, in _reverse_with_prefix
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 298, in _populate
    p_pattern = pattern.regex.pattern
AttributeError: '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'regex'
[29/Sep/2016 13:23:13]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Comment: is there no stacktrace popping up together with the error?

Comment: can you add your stacktrace?

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: okay, i added the full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stray `reverse_lazy()` in your urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name = "homepage.html")),
    reverse_lazy("homepage.html"),
```

Comment: I know, but I put that in there because when I take it out i get a different error (NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []) If i can't use reverse_lazy there, do you know what I can do to not get either one of those errors?

Comment: Well, adding more errors will definitely not fix the first one :P I can't tell you much without more details. However, since it is essentially a different question, please post a new question with the details (traceback etc.) about the `NoReverseMatch` error.